# Android client socket not connecting to python server socket

Tags: java, python, android, sockets, networking

So i created this server in python which I tested with a python client and a java client (both running on the same pc as the server cuz I only have one pc) just to be sure, and they both work fine. However when I create a socket from android (on the same wifi not an emulator) and try to connect it to the server I get the following exception https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrT9P.png.
Following are the python server code

```js
import socket
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread
import pyqrcode
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import time
import re
from tkinter import messagebox


def close_window():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
        gui.stop_connection()
        window.destroy()

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.listen_socket = None
        self.data = ''
        self.running = 0
        self.addr = None
        self.conn = None
        self.thread = None

        self.label = tk.Label(root, text="Your qr code will be displayed below",
                              bg='#05499E', fg='white', padx=10, pady=10)
        self.label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        self.host_name = socket.gethostname()
        ip_add = socket.gethostbyname(self.host_name)
        qr = pyqrcode.create(ip_add, mode='binary')
        save = qr.png('ip_add.png', 9)
        self.my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('I:\\Pycharm Projects\\QRCodeApp\\ip_add.png'))
        self.image_label = tk.Label(image=self.my_img)
        self.image_label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        self.start_btn = tk.Button(
            window, text="Start connection",
            command=self.start_connection, fg='#05499E', bg='white',
            font=('Helvetica', 16), bd=2, padx=5, pady=5, relief='solid'
        )
        self.start_btn.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        self.stop_btn = tk.Button(
            window, text="Stop connection",
            command=self.stop_connection, fg='#05499E', bg='white',
            font=('Helvetica', 16), bd=2, padx=5, pady=5, relief='solid'
        )
        self.stop_btn.pack(pady=10)

        self.connection_status = tk.Label(
            root, text="Not connected", fg='red', font=('Helvetica', 16)
        )
        self.connection_status.pack(pady=10)

    def socket_thread(self):
        print("Thread started...")
        self.listen_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        port = 65432
        host = '192.168.56.1'
        self.listen_socket.bind((host, port))
        print(f"Server is listening on port {port}")
        self.listen_socket.listen(10)
        while self.running != 0:
            if self.conn is None:
                try:
                    print('Before accepting')
                    (self.conn, self.addr) = self.listen_socket.accept()
                    print(f"Client is at address {self.addr[0]}, on port {self.addr[1]}")
                    self.connection_status.configure(text='Connected!', fg='green')

                except socket.timeout as se:
                    print("Connection timeout")

                except Exception as e:
                    print('Exception while connecting : ' + str(e))

            if self.conn is not None:
                print(f"Connected to {self.conn}, at {self.addr}")
                self.data = ''
                while self.data != 'done':
                    self.data = ''
                    try:
                        self.data = str(self.conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8'))
                        match = re.search('[A-Za-z0-9].*[A-Za-z0-9]', self.data)
                        self.data = match.group()

                    except Exception as e:
                        print("Socket error : " + str(e))

                    if len(self.data):
                        print('Got data :', self.data)
                    elif self.running == 0:
                        print('Tired of waiting for connection')
                        self.data = 'done'
                        # self.stop_connection()
                print('Closing connection...')
                self.conn = None
                self.connection_status.configure(text="Not connected", fg='red')
                print('Connection closed.')

        print("Closing listener...")
        self.conn.close()
        self.listen_socket.close()

    def start_connection(self):
        if self.running == 0:
            print('Starting thread...')
            self.running = 1
            self.thread = Thread(target=self.socket_thread)
            self.thread.start()
        else:
            print('Thread already running !')

    def stop_connection(self):

        if self.running:
            print('Stopping thread...')
            self.connection_status.configure(text="Not connected", fg='red')
            self.running = 0
            self.thread.join(timeout=0.05)
            self.thread = None
            self.data = ''
            print('thread stopped')
        else:
            print('Thread not running!')


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("QR Code Generator")
window.iconbitmap("qr.ico")
window.configure(bg='#0E7EFF')
window.geometry('400x600+500+50')
window.pack_slaves()

gui = GUI(window)

window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", close_window)
window.mainloop()
```

and the android message sending activity code where I actually make the connection

```js
package com.example.qrandbarcode;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MessageSender extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    DataOutputStream dos;
    Socket socket;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... voids) {
        String message = voids[0];
        Log.e("REACHED MESSENGER CLASS", "outside try catch");
        try{
            Log.e("BEFORE SOCKET CREATION", "Socket will be created after this");
            socket = new Socket("192.168.56.1", 65432);
            Log.e("CONNECTION", "status: " + socket.isConnected());
            dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeUTF(message);
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("EXCEPTION OCCURRED", "couldn't connect" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Following is the stacktrace of the exception

```js
E/REACHED MESSENGER CLASS: outside try catch
E/BEFORE SOCKET CREATION: Socket will be created after this
E/EXCEPTION OCCURRED: couldn't connectfailed to connect to /192.168.56.1 (port 65432) from /:: (port 57684): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.56.1 (port 65432) from /:: (port 57684): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

Please note that everything on the python GUI works fine. Please tell me what issues are there ? I know one thing that the socket doesn't connect to the server.

Comment: Could you edit the question to include the error message and stack trace **as text**?

Comment: Since the initial TCP connection failed with a timeout I assume that there is some firewall blocking the connection. Given that it is inside the same network it might be the firewall or AV on the machine where your server is running.

Comment: @Joni Yes sure.

Comment: @SteffenUlrich I disabled all 3 types of firewall on windows and also asked the internet permissions on android. What else do I need to do?

Comment: As said before: do not bind your server to an ip address. host = '192.168.56.1' Do not bind at all or bind to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: @blackapps Yes android client socket not connecting to my python server socket. I tired binding the server to '0.0.0.0' still the phone didn't connect and not binding at all gave me error at the listen statement : OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied